# Datetime add timespan without showing the date VB

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

I am currently running this code, and it displays the date as Output shown below.

```
Dim started As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim date As DateTime = started.Add(diaryItem.Duration)
```

> Output : 23/03/2016 17:00:00

Is it possible to remove the date and only show the time ?

Comment: I guess We'll need more code, as your question is unclear... With that line of code, no output should be displayed...

Comment: Still no Output, Where do you output any data ? Is this a console application or a Windows Form Application ?

Comment: Ah I'm so silly, sorry I haven't given enough information, I didn't want to write all my code on here, but tried to make it simple as possible, clearly didn't work.
Also I made a silly mistake :S I was looking at the wrong code in my application, that's why the time wasn't working.

Comment: I don't mind this being deleted. 
sqlProfiler87 got it right though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to see time from datetime then try this:

```
'show time

Dim OnlyTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")

'or

Dim OnlyTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString
```

If you only want to see date from datetime then try this:

```
'show date

     dateOnly = myDateTime.Date
'or 
     dateString = dateOnly.ToShortDateString()
```

If this is not what you are looking for then put more informations..

[DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)